# How can I generate a BigQuery result without JSON formatting?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I've been adapting the asynch_query.py script found at the [bigquery-python-samples github repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-samples-python/blob/master/python/samples/async_query.py) to return data from google bigquery.  As written the section of code that returns the results produces a list of items in JSON format.

```
def run(project_id, query_string, batch, num_retries, interval):
service = get_service()query_job = async_query(service,
                        project_id,
                        query_string,
                        batch,
                        num_retries)

poll_job(service,
         query_job['jobReference']['projectId'],
         query_job['jobReference']['jobId'],
         interval,
         num_retries)


for page in paging(service,
                   service.jobs().getQueryResults,
                   num_retries=num_retries,
                   **query_job['jobReference']):

    yield json.dumps(page['rows'])`
```

My query returns a single item: MAX value of one field. I want to change the script to return a string object so the results can be concatenated to another string object.  With the code above I get a value like this: [<"f": [<"v": "ga_sessions_20150505">]>].

I need it to return just the query result: "ga_sessions_20150505" without the JSON ornamentation.  I've been unsuccessful in adjusting the script to produce this outcome.  My goal is to create a function that can be called from another python script and assign the result to a variable for further use.  Can someone provide some assistance or point me to a resource that will help?

Comment: Having continued to try and figure this out I see now that this is not JSON formating but rather represents a Python dictionary structure.  However, when I 'type' the output, it identifies it as a string.  I would still like to figure out how to output the desired value, although now knowing it is a string I could apply string functions to strip it down to what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
for page in paging(service,
                   service.jobs().getQueryResults,
                   num_retries=num_retries,
                   **query_job['jobReference']):
  for row in page['rows']:
    # Each row is a dict with fields, 'f', containing
    # an array of table cells, one for each column
    # of the query output. Each cell is a dict
    # containing a value, 'v'.
    yield row['f'][0]['v']  # This query generates 1 column.
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  You're correct.  I was looking for a way to pull out just the value from the Python object.  Of course, I had to first understand the object, which took me a bit, since I'm a novice when it comes to Python.  I've finally got it working.  Given my novice skills this was a good learning exercise.